Fixed column width and left alignment works partially
For some reason, I am not able to set left alignment in the third column of a table (I can make it only in the first and second columns}. Does anybody know waht is hapenning? Below you find a MWE.
Thanks in advance,
Marcus.
\documentclass [chapterprefix=true,pagesize=false,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,fontsize=10pt,twoside,open=right,cleardoublepage=empty,headsepline=off]{scrbook}
\usepackage[driver=none]{geometry}
\geometry{
    mag=1000,
    paperheight=24.0cm, paperwidth=17.0cm,
    height=20.8cm, width=13.2cm,
    textheight=19.8cm, textwidth=13.2cm,
    headheight=0.5cm, headsep=0.5cm,
    includehead,
    twoside,
    inner=2.0cm, outer=2.0cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=1.7cm,
    nomarginpar
    }
\usepackage[a4,center,cam,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\crop
\usepackage [table]{xcolor}
\usepackage [brazilian] {babel}
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage {caption}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage {ragged2e}

\newcommand{\legenda}[1]{\caption {#1}}

\newcommand {\tab}[3]{
    \begin{table} [bht]
    \centering
    \legenda{#2}
    \label {#1}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    #3
    \end{table}
}

\begin {document}
\tab{202407151017}{Tipos de lógica}
{
\begin {tabular} {| >{\raggedright}m{3cm} | >{\raggedright}m{3cm} | >{\raggedright}m{3cm} |}
\hline
                                               & \textbf {SEM} quantificação sobre termos & \textbf {COM} quantificação sobre termos \\
\hline
\textbf {SEM} quantificação sobre proposições  & Lógica proposicional de 1ª ordem         & Lógica proposicional de 2ª ordem \\
\hline
\textbf {COM} quantificação sobre proposições  & Lógica de predicados de 1ª ordem         & Lógica de predicados de 2ª ordem \\
\hline
\end {tabular}
}\end {document}


Use >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}:
\documentclass [chapterprefix=true,pagesize=false,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,fontsize=10pt,twoside,open=right,cleardoublepage=empty,headsepline=off]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    mag=1000,
    paperheight=24.0cm, paperwidth=17.0cm,
    height=20.8cm, width=13.2cm,
    textheight=19.8cm, textwidth=13.2cm,
    headheight=0.5cm, headsep=0.5cm,
    includehead,
    twoside,
    inner=2.0cm, outer=2.0cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=1.7cm,
    nomarginpar
    }
\usepackage[a4,center,cam,noinfo]{crop}
\crop
\usepackage [table]{xcolor}
\usepackage [brazilian] {babel}
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage {caption}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage {ragged2e}

\newcommand{\legenda}[1]{\caption {#1}}

\newcommand {\tab}[3]{
    \begin{table} [bht]
    \centering
    \legenda{#2}
    \label {#1}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    #3
    \end{table}
}

\begin {document}
\tab{202407151017}{Tipos de lógica}
{
\begin {tabular} {| >{\raggedright}m{3cm} | >{\raggedright}m{3cm} | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm} |}
\hline
                                               & \textbf {SEM} quantificação sobre termos & \textbf {COM} quantificação sobre termos \\
\hline
\textbf {SEM} quantificação sobre proposições  & Lógica proposicional de 1ª ordem         & Lógica proposicional de 2ª ordem \\
\hline
\textbf {COM} quantificação sobre proposições  & Lógica de predicados de 1ª ordem         & Lógica de predicados de 2ª ordem \\
\hline
\end {tabular}
}\end {document}

Or use the tabularray package:
\documentclass [chapterprefix=true,pagesize=false,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,fontsize=10pt,twoside,open=right,cleardoublepage=empty,headsepline=off]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    mag=1000,
    paperheight=24.0cm, paperwidth=17.0cm,
    height=20.8cm, width=13.2cm,
    textheight=19.8cm, textwidth=13.2cm,
    headheight=0.5cm, headsep=0.5cm,
    includehead,
    twoside,
    inner=2.0cm, outer=2.0cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=1.7cm,
    nomarginpar
    }
\usepackage[a4,center,cam,noinfo]{crop}
\crop
\usepackage [table]{xcolor}
\usepackage [brazilian] {babel}
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage {caption}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage {ragged2e}

\newcommand{\legenda}[1]{\caption {#1}}

\newcommand {\tab}[3]{
    \begin{table} [bht]
    \centering
    \legenda{#2}
    \label {#1}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    #3
    \end{table}
}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin {document}
\tab{202407151017}{Tipos de lógica}
{
\begin {tblr} {
  colspec={Q[3cm] Q[3cm] Q[3cm]},
  vlines,hlines,
  cells={halign=l}
}
& \textbf {SEM} quantificação sobre termos & \textbf {COM} quantificação sobre termos \\
\textbf {SEM} quantificação sobre proposições  & Lógica proposicional de 1ª ordem         & Lógica proposicional de 2ª ordem \\
\textbf {COM} quantificação sobre proposições  & Lógica de predicados de 1ª ordem         & Lógica de predicados de 2ª ordem \\
\end {tblr}
}\end {document}


Thank you very much.

@Marcus You're welcome!
